# Oracle SQL to get values between 2 special characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a `Oracle` SQL query to get value `'LATCH'` From `'RTG/LATCH.PETROL_ABC'`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
select regexp_replace('RTG/LATCH.PETROL_ABC', '.*/(.+)\..*', '\1' ) from dual
```

First we find matches:

**.*/** match **RTG/**

**(.+)** match **LATCH** and marked match as group 1

**\..*** match **.PETROL_ABC**

Then we replace whole string by group 1 from matches use **\1**

Comment: Thanks for your help and can you explain how it works... I'm not able to figure out the function..

Comment: Regular Expressions have a bit of a learning curve, but are extremely powerful if you often do text manipulations. This website gives a great introduction: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @user2469253 I'm try to explain in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUBSTR() and INSTR(),

```
SELECT SUBSTR('RTG/LATCH.PETROL_ABC',
    INSTR('RTG/LATCH.PETROL_ABC', '/') + 1,
    INSTR('RTG/LATCH.PETROL_ABC', '.') - INSTR('RTG/LATCH.PETROL_ABC', '/') - 1)
```